# Using Cookie in Asp.Net Mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, action, httpcookie

I have web application in *Asp.Net MVC4* and I want to use **cookie** for user's login and logout. So my actions as follows:

*Login Action*

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string username, string pass)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var newUser = _userRepository.GetUserByNameAndPassword(username, pass);
            if (newUser != null)
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newUser);

                var userCookie = new HttpCookie("user", json);
                userCookie.Expires.AddDays(365);
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(userCookie);

                return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index");
            }
        }
        return View("UserLog");
    }
```

*LogOut Action*

```
    public ActionResult UserOut()
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["user"] != null)
        {
            var user = new HttpCookie("user")
                {
                    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                    Value = null
                };
            Response.Cookies.Add(user);
        }
        return RedirectToActionPermanent("UserLog");
    }
```

And I use this cookie in _Loyout as follow:

```
@using EShop.Core
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@{
   var userInCookie = Request.Cookies["user"];
}
...
  @if (userInCookie != null && userInCookie.Value)
  {
        <li><a href="#">Salam</a></li>
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("UserOut", "Home")">Cıxış</a></li>
  }
  else
  {
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("UserLog", "Home")">Giriş</a></li>
  }
```

But When I *click* *UserOut* action this action happen first time, but then it doesn't work. I put breakpoint for looking process but it get *UserLog* action doesn't *UserOut*. 
My question is that where I use wrong way of cookie? What is a best way using cookie in *Asp.Net Mvc4* for this scenario ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Forms Authentication?

Comment: How can I use its? I know this, but don't deeply, so I can't use Forms Authentication. I have some special process and I afraid that can't do their with Forms Authentication.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Try using `Response.SetCookie()`, because `Response.Cookies.Add()` can cause multiple cookies to be added, whereas `SetCookie` will update an existing cookie.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but it doesn't work again. please watch this http://screencast.com/t/eMeFnm6Hq

Comment: It is very strange. Why my LogOut Action doesn't handled with break point?!  but RedirectToActionParmenently work fine :(

Comment: So the issue only occurs if you use `RedirectToAction()`?

Comment: Thanks! Response.SetCookie() does help.

Answer (score 15):

We are using `Response.SetCookie()` for update the old one cookies and `Response.Cookies.Add()` are use to add the new cookies. Here below code `CompanyId` is update in old `cookie[OldCookieName]`.

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["OldCookieName"];//Get the existing cookie by cookie name.
cookie.Values["CompanyID"] = Convert.ToString(CompanyId);
Response.SetCookie(cookie); //SetCookie() is used for update the cookie.
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie); //The Cookie.Add() used for Add the cookie.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
userCookie.Expires.AddDays(365);
```

This line of code doesn't do anything. It is the equivalent of:

```
DateTime temp = userCookie.Expires.AddDays(365); 
//do nothing with temp
```

You probably want

```
userCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365);
```