# cookies value not set

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

in my project cookies value not set,i can't understand why,where the problem i cant find out .please help

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult sellerLogin(string userid,string password)
    {

        int count = db.sellers.Count(p => p.userId == userid && p.password == password);
        if (count == 1)
        {
            HttpCookie selleruserid = new HttpCookie("selleruserid");
            selleruserid["selleruserid"] = userid.ToString();
            selleruserid.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(220);
            Response.Cookies.Add(selleruserid);                
            return View("loginSuccess");
        }


        return View();
    }
```

**loginSuccess()** Action result is

```
 public ActionResult loginSuccess()
    {
        HttpCookie selleruserid = Request.Cookies["selleruserid"];
        if (selleruserid != null)
        {
            ViewBag.userid = selleruserid["selleruserid"].ToString();

        } 


        return View();
    }
```

**loginSuccess()** View contain

```
@ViewBag.userid
```

but when control goes to loginsuccess then viewbag showing blank...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Cookie in Asp.Net Mvc 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128507/using-cookie-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Response.SetCookie()`, because `Response.Cookie.Add()` can cause multiple cookies to be added, whereas `SetCookie` will update an existing cookie.

Better if you add logic to check if cookie already exists then `Response.SetCookie` else `Response.Cookie.Add`

Answer (score 0):

Hi your code working fine for me,
if you are using viewbag and any redirection occurred then your viewbag will be null, you can also use this Response.SetCookie(selleruserid);