# Cookies - How to get the previous last login datetime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have the following code from the site master (where the login form is)

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        Response.Cookies["LastLogin"].Value = dt.ToString();
        Response.Cookies["LastLogin"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365);
    }
```

So basically I save the current datetime in a cookie when a users logs in.

Then in the profile review page, I wrote the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["LastLogin"] != null)
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = Request.Cookies["LastLogin"].Value;
                }
         }}
```

The thing is that it works (it displays the date and time), but not for the previous log in but for the actual login, obviously, but thats why I'm asking - How can I solve this without having to do anything with database? How can I not "override" the previous value but also save the new one?

Comment: Maybe I should create a string array and then when I Request the cookie, request the i-1 value? I don't know if that is possible though, I'm new with cookie codes

Comment: take a look at my answer and let me know if it works for you? Thanks!

Comment: @degant Sorry for late response! Yes it works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using one cookie `LastLogin` to save the last login information which can used by rest of your application and `CurrentLogin` to save current login timestamp.

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    if (Response.Cookies["CurrentLogin"] != null)
    {
        HttpCookie oldLoginCookie = new HttpCookie("LastLogin")
        {
            Expires = Response.Cookies["CurrentLogin"].Expires,
            Value = Response.Cookies["CurrentLogin"].Value
        };
        Response.SetCookie(oldLoginCookie);
    }
    HttpCookie loginCookie = new HttpCookie("CurrentLogin")
    {
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365),
        Value = dt.ToString()
    };
    Response.Cookies.Add(loginCookie);
}
```

Also using `SetCookie()` instead of `Cookies.Add()` to avoid multiple cookies from being added as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19141852/1186936). Your `Page_Load` methods should work as-is as long as you make the above changes.

Answer (score 0):

When doing the login, you can store the *previous* date (`Response.Cookies["LastLogin"].Value`, before overwriting it) into a new cookie - then check this new cookie in your page load.

You do need to check that the `LastLogin` is not empty, in case this is the very first login.

Something like this:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Request.Cookies["LastLogin"] != null)
    {
         Request.Cookies["PrevLogin"].Value = Request.Cookies["LastLogin"].Value;
         Request.Cookies["PrevLogin"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365);
    }

    string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    Response.Cookies["LastLogin"].Value = dt.ToString();
    Response.Cookies["LastLogin"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365);
}
```

Comment: Hmm I'm getting an error at line Request.Cookies["PrevLogin"].Value = Request.Cookies["LastLogin"].Value; as Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.